# jq: Creating string out of JSON containing optional fields and conditionals

Tags: json, jq

I'm having the following JSON code:

```
{
  "main": {
    "files": [
      {
        "name": "ca.crt",
        "type": "static"
      },
      {
        "name": "key",
        "type": "dynamic"
      },
      {
        "name": "crt",
        "type": "dynamic"
      }
    ],
    "FOO": "BAR",
    "BLA": "BLUB"
  },
  "ota": {
    "EEKS": "POOPS",
    "files": [
      {
        "name": "ca.crt",
        "type": "static"
      },
      {
        "name": "sig.pub",
        "type": "static"
      }
    ]
  },
  "random": {
    "files": [
      {
        "type": "dynamic"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

which I'd like to transform into the following string:

```
static/main.ca.crt.der
dynamic/main.key
dynamic/main.crt
static/ota.ca.crt
static/ota.sig.pub
dynamic/random
```

Main caveats here are:
 - There are optional fields within the struct - especially 'name' (see `"random": {"files": [{"type": "dynamic"}]' -> 'dynamic/random')`

Closest I got so far was via:

`jq 'to_entries[] | .value.files[].type + "/" + .key + "/" + .value.files[].name' < /tmp/config.json`

resulting in:

```
"static/main/ca.crt"
"dynamic/main/ca.crt"
"dynamic/main/ca.crt"
"static/main/key"
"dynamic/main/key"
"dynamic/main/key"
"static/main/crt"
"dynamic/main/crt"
"dynamic/main/crt"
"static/ota/ca.crt"
"static/ota/ca.crt"
"static/ota/sig.pub"
"static/ota/sig.pub"
"dynamic/random/"
```

As you can see it has several issues:

- duplicates
- created strings out of non-existing keys (e.g. while `"static/main/ca.crt"` is correct, `"dynamic/main/ca.crt"` and `"dynamic/main/ca.crt"` are not).
- `"dynamic/random/"` should be `"dynamic/random"` (without trailing slash)

If jq can't to that by itself (in one call), I'm happy about suggestions involving multiple calls and/or additional sh-scripting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional fields can be handled using an `if-then-else` statement. And you don't need `to_entries` here, just keep keys in a variable.

```
$ jq -r 'keys_unsorted[] as $k | .[$k].files[] | .type + "/" + $k +
if has("name") then "." + .name else "" end' file.json
static/main.ca.crt
dynamic/main.key
dynamic/main.crt
static/ota.ca.crt
static/ota.sig.pub
dynamic/random
```